# jQuery: Removing Browser Generated Title Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to remove the browser generated title box that appears with anchors that have a title attribute. The reason I want to do this is so it doesn't interfere with my tooltip jQuery.

As of right now I am removing the title attr on hover, but it won't reassign it after removing yourself from the hover state. How come?

http://jsfiddle.net/fj4xz/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because the

```
var title
```

is in the HandlerIn function and not defined in the handler out.
Simplest solution is to put de var title outside of your hover function and assign it inside the hover handlers.

Edit: Removing the vars as stated by Photon is also a solution. I highly recommend you use vars though. Your code soon gets messy and unmaintainable if variables that are global are not defined. But thats just my opinion.

http://jsfiddle.net/RubenJonker/fj4xz/6/

Comment: I didn't said not to use var but i think nothing get messy and unmaintainable without var if you wanna use variable as a global variable. if you want to declare any variable as global it's easy and user friendly to declare where u want to use it first time rather bothering about do declare out of function or at start.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `title` variable is within the `mouseenter` function, but you're using it inside `mouseleave`. You should move your `title` variable outside the `hover` method.

```
var title;
$('a.tooltip').hover(function() {
    title = $(this).attr('title');
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var width = $(this).outerWidth();
    var height = $(this).outerHeight();
    $content = $('<div class="tooltip">' + title + '</div>').fadeIn('fast');
    $(this).append($content);
    $(this).attr('title', '');
    $content.offset({
        top: offset.top + height,
        left: offset.left + (width - $content.outerWidth()) / 2
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).find('div').fadeOut('fast');
    $(this).attr('title', title);
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring `var title = $(this).attr('title');` in your first function there, but your second function has no knowledge of `title`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it won't re-assign the title value is because you're declaring the title variable in the first function, which is out of the scope of the second. If you want to preserve the original title value, you need to do so in such a way the second function has access to it.

Instead, try adding it to a data value:

```
$(this).data("originalTitle", $(this).attr("title"));
```

And then re-assign it within your second function:

```
$(this).attr("title", $(this).data("originalTitle"));
```

I would avoid having a generic `title` variable floating around that you're setting and getting for *n* links on the page. Storing the values as data on the element itself seems like a far better approach to me.

Answer (score 0):

just **remove** all **var** declarations before variable name

it will become global variable [See this](http://jsfiddle.net/fj4xz/5/)

```
  $('a.tooltip').hover(function() {
        title = $(this).attr('title');
         offset = $(this).offset();
         width = $(this).outerWidth();
         height = $(this).outerHeight();
        $content = $('<div class="tooltip">' + title + '</div>').fadeIn('fast');
        $(this).append($content);
        $(this).attr('title', '');
        $content.offset({ top: offset.top+height, left: offset.left+(width-$content.outerWidth())/2 });
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('div').fadeOut('fast');
        $(this).attr('title', title);
    });​
```